# Push dropped item to Array using jQuery UI?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm trying to push a word's ID to a list once it's dropped using jQuery UI's droppable feature. When I drag and drop the word the `console.log()` gives me the correct ID. However my `.push()` call below does nothing. How do I push the given ID?

Goal:

Before drop: One, Two,

After drop: One, Two, Three,

JavaScript:

```
var words = ["One,Two,"];
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = words.toString();

$(move);

function move() {
  $('#moving').draggable();
  $('#drop').droppable({
    drop: handleDropEvent
  });
}

function handleDropEvent(event, ui) {
  var draggable = ui.draggable;
  var droppable = ui.droppable;
  var word = ui.draggable.attr('id') 
  words.push(word)
  console.log(word)
  $('#moving').hide(draggable.attr);
}
```

HTML:

```
<p id="demo"></p>

<div>
   <span id="Three">
      <strong> Three </strong>
   </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Your `words` array contains one item, which is a string `"One,Two,"`. Shouldn't it be `["One", "Two"]`? Instead of using `.toString()` you should rather use `.join()` and explicitly specify the delimiter you want to use.

Comment: You have `#moving` and `#drop` as your draggable and droppable but no such elements in your HTML example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `#demo` element doesn't automagically update when you change the `words` variable. You have to manually update it:

```
var words = ["One,Two,"];
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = words.toString();

$(move);

function move() {
  $('#moving').draggable();
  $('#drop').droppable({
    drop: handleDropEvent
  });
}

function handleDropEvent(event, ui) {
  var draggable = ui.draggable;
  var droppable = ui.droppable;
  var word = ui.draggable.attr('id') 
  words.push(word)
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = words.toString();
  console.log(word)
  $('#moving').hide(draggable.attr);
}
```